# Fade in Each Thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery

all of my thumbnails have the class .thumb

I'm trying to fade in each at a time like I've seen on some websites but it doesnt seem to be working. My code is below

```
$('.thumb').eachDelay(function(){ 
    $(this).fadeIn('1000'); 
}, 100);
```

What is wrong here?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NPWGu/

I've tried a ton of the solutions and havent had any luck yet so hopefully this will help make it easier to understand how I have my code setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".thumb").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(500*i).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Comment: hmm that didn't work either.. seemed to fade them all in at once

Comment: the fade was actually from the whole fade fading in, so it didnt fade at all

Comment: @JoeBobby my bad, anwser updated. Also see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bB6cY/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any jQuery method called `eachDelay()`.  As it is not quite clear from your question which exact scenario you want, here are four different different options:

**1) If you want to fade them all in at once, you would use this:**

```
$('.thumb').fadeIn('1000');
```

**2) If you want to fade them all in at the same time after delay, you can use this:**

```
$('.thumb').delay(1000).fadeIn('1000');
```

**3) If you want to fade them all in one after another, you can use this:**

```
function sequentialFade(selector) {
    var items$ = $(selector);
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < items$.length) {
            items$.eq(index++).fadeIn('1000', next);
        }
    }
    next();
}

sequentialFade('.thumb');
```

**4) If you want to fade them all in one after another with a delay between the finish of one and the start of the next, you can use this:**

```
function sequentialFade(selector, delayTime) {
    var items$ = $(selector);
    var index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < items$.length) {
            items$.eq(index++).delay(delayTime).fadeIn(1000, next);
        }
    }
    next();
}

sequentialFade('.thumb', 1000);
```

Working demonstration of this last option here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zg8S4/

Comment: I'm not trying to fade in all the thumbnails at once but after thumbnail 1 fades in i want a short amount of time before thumbnail 2 fades in.. and then a short amount of time before thumbnail 3 fades in

Comment: @JoeBobby - OK, the last option in my answer does what you just asked for.  Your question was not very clear on which exact option you wanted.

Comment: @JoeBobby - Added a working demonstration of the last option in my answer that fades in the thumbs sequentially with a delay between each one: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zg8S4/.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! I updated the main post with a fiddle aroudn the same time you put this up I'll test this out and see how it works

Answer (score 0):

Serial animation code should look like (you can change the 1000ms below as needed):

```
var cur = -1;
var thumbs = $(".thumb");
function doIt() {
  if(cur == -1) cur = 0;
  else if(cur < thumbs.length-1) cur++;
  else return;
  $(thumbs[cur]).fadeIn(1000, doIt);
}
doIt();
```

Comment: Updated my answer with a minor correction. The previous version assumed that the thumbs were sibling elements in the HTML.

Comment: `cur.next()` is not guaranteed to find the next thumb.  That would only be the case if all thumbs were siblings of the same parent with no intervening non-thumb siblings.

Comment: @jfriend00 - You are right. Thats why i updated the answer. :)